# C# How to pass a generic type of enum as a variable into a function...?

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I want to make a static generic function to handle all cases about that make a Dictionary and return it.
I write a function like this.

```
public static Dictionary<string, T> GetDictionaryNameToEnum<T>(IEnumerable<T> type)
{
    Dictionary<string, T> dict = new Dictionary<string, T> ();
    foreach (T value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))) {
        dict.Add (value.ToString (), value);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

but when i invoke the function like this.

```
public enum FlipType
{
    normal,
    y4,
    x4,
    y4x4,
}

static Dictionary<string, FlipType> FlipNameToType = new Dictionary<string, FlipType> ();
public static FlipType GetFlipType(string flipTypeName)
{
    if (FlipNameToType == null) {
        FlipNameToType = GameUtil.GetDictionaryNameToEnum (FlipType);
    }

    return FlipNameToType [flipTypeName];
}
```

I get a compile issue.

> Error CS0118: 'macehead.GameWrapperBrickSet.FlipType' is a 'type' but a 'variable' was expected (CS0118) (Assembly-CSharp)

How can I invoke this function? And Can I do it like this Or there has a better way.

Comment: This error is expectable. You pass `FlipType` to your method while it is a type.

Comment: Method arguments are for passing instances. Why not simply lose the `type` argument which you're not enumerating anyway? You can then simply call the method like so: `GetDictionaryNameToEnum<FlipType>()`

Comment: @Biscuits Hahaha...You are so smart!!Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it can help you。

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write(GetFlipType("normal"));
    }

    static Dictionary<string, FlipType> FlipNameToType = new Dictionary<string, FlipType>();
    public static FlipType GetFlipType(string flipTypeName)
    {
        if (FlipNameToType == null || FlipNameToType.Count == 0)
        {
            FlipNameToType = default(FlipType).ToDictionaryMembersEx();
        }

        return FlipNameToType[flipTypeName];
    }

    public enum FlipType
    {
        normal,
        y4,
        x4,
        y4x4,
    }

}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<string, TEnum> ToDictionaryMembersEx<TEnum>(this TEnum source) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
    {
        Dictionary<string, TEnum> dict = new Dictionary<string, TEnum>();
        foreach (TEnum value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
        {
            dict.Add(value.ToString(), value);
        }
        return dict;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is expectable. You pass `FlipType` to your method while it is a type.
This would be a correct usage of your method:

```
FlipNameToType = GameUtil.GetDictionaryNameToEnum<FlipType>(null);
```

`null` is because usage of `IEnumerable<T> type` method parameter is absolutely unclear, and you actually don't use it inside your method. Perhaps, you just need to remove this parameter.

Your code is overcomplicated and unclear, in general.
If you need to know `FlipType` by its name, then you don't need to store values in `Dictionary`, you can just use `Enum.Parse` or `Enum.TryParse`:

```
public static FlipType GetFlipType(string flipTypeName)
{
    FlipType parsed; // in C# 7.0 can be simplified into 'out FlipType parsed'

    if (!Enum.TryParse<FlipType>(flipTypeName, out parsed)
    {
        throw new OutOfRangeException(nameof(flipTypeName));
    } 

    return parsed;
}
```

Note that this code throws `OutOfRangeException` if `flipTypeName` does not match any `FlipType` enumeration value. However, your code does the same - it would throw exception if no key has is found in `Dictionary<string, T>`.

Comment: Thanks!I have never noticed TryParse() function before.It's a powerful function.But I think the performance of it is worse than searching dictionary.

Comment: @RockEar Code is not only about performance. Performant, but unreadable and unmaintainable code is worse than ineffictive one line of code. [**Premature optimization is the root of all evil**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil). You may start to worry about "dictionary lookup vs enum parse performance" when you call this method ~100 000 000 times per second. If you stlil don't, then focus on code quality, not performance.